# Mosquitto MQTT TLS over Websockets

Tags: javascript, mqtt, mosquitto

I have gone through a few pages about the same topic but could not find the correct method to implement TLS over websockets in mosquitto. This is my mosquitto conf file. The certs are in my certs folder.

```
# Place your local configuration in /etc/mosquitto/conf.d/
#
# A full description of the configuration file is at
# /usr/share/doc/mosquitto/examples/mosquitto.conf.example

pid_file /var/run/mosquitto.pid

persistence true
persistence_location /var/lib/mosquitto/

log_dest file /var/log/mosquitto/mosquitto.log

include_dir /etc/mosquitto/conf.d

listener 9001
protocol websockets
require_certificate false
cafile /etc/mosquitto/certs/ca.crt
certfile /etc/mosquitto/certs/server.crt
keyfile /etc/mosquitto/certs/server.key

listener 1883
protocol mqtt
```

The error generated on the web page console is:

```
mqtt.min.js:1 WebSocket connection to 'wss://ip:9001/' failed: Error in connection establishment: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
```

Comment: You have opened port 9001 in any firewall running on the machine? Also double check the mosquitto logs, it will log which ports it's listening on at startup

Comment: Yeah. It is open.

Comment: And the logs show that it is listening on port 9001?

Comment: Yes. It is not able to use the certifcates.

Comment: So edit the question to show the logs so we can suggest how to fix it